# mini_magick thumbnail with gravity center

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I want to create a padded thumbnail, like [described here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad)

This command works:

```
convert src.png -thumbnail '200x200>' -gravity center -extent '200x200' dst.png
```

But this *ruby* code is not working: gravity is ignored

```
require 'mini_magick'
image = MiniMagick::Image.open('src.png')
image.thumbnail '200x200>'
image.gravity 'center'
image.extent '200x200'
image.write 'dst.png'
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `combine_options` with MiniMagick to roll all three of your commands together before you write it:

```
require 'mini_magick'
image = MiniMagick::Image.open('src.png')
image.combine_options do |c|
  c.thumbnail '200x200>'
  c.gravity 'center'
  c.extent '200x200'
end
image.write 'dst.png'
```

More info on the [GitHub docs](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick)